# Replace '~' with a newline ('\n') using replace(p){r, t} conversion in logback.xml

Tags: regex, replace, newline, logback

I am trying to replace `~` with a newline `\n` using `replace(p){r, t}` conversion in logback.xml.

I have the pattern layout like

```
%p %c [%t] \\(%M:%L\\) - %replace(%msg){'~', '\n'}  %nopex %n
```

When I put `\n`, logback changes it to 'n'. But if I put `'\\\n'` then it keeps both the backslashes i.e. it retains `'\\\n'`. Before getting deep into the source code of logback, I wanted to check if anybody ever tried/faced it?

To me, it seems we can't add newline to the message using the replace method!

It adds an extra escape character (`\\`).

Comment: I've edited your code with code formating, please, check if the `\\ ` are still what you want them to be

Comment: What kind of regex flavour are you referring to?

Comment: this is used by logback, so should be java regex pattern. Aside, in the logback xml it accepts '\n' as regex for newline.

Comment: The funniest part is, logback resolves `\n` as `\\n` while reading from the config file. So even `%replace(%msg){"\n", "\n"}` doesn't work!! The newlilne char are replaced with `\\n`

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround is to use regex capture group:
`<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %replace(%msg){'(\n)','$1'}%n</pattern>`

But it is still not possible to add other escaped char like a tab '\t'

I opened an issue https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1261

Comment: any luck on this? I want to replace \n with \r for multiline logstash

Comment: I am using logback 1.2.3 and doing this: %replace(%msg){'\n','\\\\t'} works like a charm .

Comment: @PhilippeSimo not working for me , logback spring boot

Answer (score 1):

To add escaped characters in logback xml configuration file, use xml character entity reference. In your case:

```
%p %c [%t] \\(%M:%L\\) - %replace(%msg){'~', '&#xa;'}  %nopex %n
```

Similarly, to replace \n in exception stack traces to \r, one could do (say if you are **scraping** the logs through an operator & ingesting it in to elastic):

```
%replace(%ex){'\n', '&#xd;'}
```

Source: Noisyfox's comment at https://github.com/symphoniacloud/lambda-monitoring/issues/4

Comment: Nice trick for AWS Lambda converting every \n to new log event on stack traces.
            ...  %msg %replace(%ex){'[\r\n]+', '&#xd;'}%nopex%n